# How to read the output of var_export into a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, associative-array

I have an txt file where I output the variable using the command :

```
$h = fopen('log.txt', 'w'); 
fwrite($h, var_export($my_var, true));
fclose($h);
```

The content of `log.txt` looks similar to this :

```
array (
  'IMType' => '1',
  'Email' => 'test@gmail.com',
  'SignupName' => 'test11',
  'Password' => '11111',
  'Encrypted' => '',
  'Confirm' => '11111',
  'OldPassword' => '',
  'Name' => 'test',
  'SignupProvinceText' => 'province',
  'SignupCity' => 'cityname',
  'Street' => 'street x.y',
  'SignupIndustry' => 'IT',
  'SignupCompany' => 'jobirn',
  'SignupJt' => 'engineer',
  'CellPhoneNum' => '',
  'linked_in' => '',
)
```

Now, I would like to read this file again (later) and convert into an associative array ?

Any idea how this can be done ?

Comment: Your handle is [write only](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) so you can't read from it, try `w+` - though the entire file contents will be replaced each time, if you want to append to the log you'd need `a+`. You might be better off with `file_put_contents` and `file_get_contents`

Comment: That being said though, you shouldn't be writing unencrypted text files containing personal information and passwords to the server anyway.

Comment: @CD001, I am not writing anything on the server. I am testing the response from the SMS Gateway by writing the response to a file ( only during development stage)

Comment: @Kiran I think it a bad practice, use a json instead. But if you are sure in security, write `'<? $array = '. var_export($my_var, true) .';'` and include the file by include_once() for example

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using serialize() and unserialize() or json_encode() and json_decode() for this task. They are more appropriate for storing data.

```
file_put_contents('path/to/your_file.txt', serialize($my_var));
```

and

```
$my_var = unserialize(file_get_contents('path/to/your_file.txt'));
```

Or for the json version:

```
file_put_contents('path/to/your_file.txt', json_encode($my_var));
```

and

```
$my_var = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/your_file.txt'), true);
```

Comment: A much better solution than trying to parse text to recreate a variable.